# The application RCApps (process com.examples) has stopped unexpectantly

Tags: android

My application was running fine but then I got the error and tried to re run the API, clean the build but nothing worked. When lookied into the logcat error found two errors with which I could find a solution for. The following are the errors.

11-08 21:50:09.981: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(352): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: android.view.Relativelayout in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/data/app/com.examples-1.apk]

11-08 21:50:09.981: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(352): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class Relativelayout

```
    The following is the contents of my class:

    public class Vathiyar extends Activity{

        private Button findvathiyar;
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.vathiyar); 

        }

    }

    Following is my xml code.. 

        <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
        <Relativelayout
         xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
         android:id="@+id/vathiyar_1"
         android:orientation = "vertical"
         android:layout_width="fill_parent"
          android:layout_height="fill_parent"
          >
        <TextView
        android:id="@+id/widget32"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="-11px"
        android:text="Welcome to the Selection of Vathiyar page"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        >
       </TextView>
        </Relativelayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is in your XML.  You have RelativeLayout spelled incorrectly.

Change:

```
<Relativelayout ...
</Relativelayout>
```

To:

```
<RelativeLayout ...
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: OMG I never knew this was this casesensitive. This is first project I am trying in Java with android, I was thinking that if there are any xml errors it would show them in compile time. It just worked. Thanks and appreciate your response.